# MYSQL - Using PREPARE and EXECUTE give me Error #1064

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a procedure that will return a table only if it a specific boolean is marked as true.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    id              INT         NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    is_grocery_store            BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_restaurant               BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_entertainment            BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_retail_store             BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_financial_institution    BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_mortgage_company         BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_medical_establishment    BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    is_insurance_agency         BIT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_company (IN CORPORATION ENUM(
        'grocery_store',
        'restaurant',
        'entertainment',
        'retail_store',
        'financial_institution',
        'mortgage_company',
        'medical_establishment',
        'insurance_agency'
    ))

    SET @sql = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE is_? = b'1'");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING FAMILY_ID, CORPORATION;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I inserted a bunch of rows and here is where I call the procedure:

```
CALL get_company('financial_institution');
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

> Please note that I am using the SQL tab on phpMyAdmin to run this code and they do not use `delimiter //` or `BEGIN` and `END`. That is not the issue.

Comment: It is **not possible to bind *identifiers*** (or fragments of identifiers or ad-hoc SQL) such as `is_financial_institution`. Parameters can *only* be used with values. To change *identifiers* the original SQL has to be manipulated *as a string/text* prior to execution (any *values* can still be bound after appropriate generation of the "dynamic SQL").

Comment: Alternatively, the query could be written like: `WHERE is_grocery_store = P1 OR is_restaurant = P2 OR ..` and binding all the parameters not used for the query to NULL - as NULL won't match 0/NULL with ANSI NULLs. (That is, only the parameter associated for "is grocery store" would be 1 when looking for [only] grocery stores..)

Answer (score 0):

Try using execute immediate for mariadb :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_company (IN CORPORATION ENUM(
    'grocery_store',
    'restaurant',
    'entertainment',
    'retail_store',
    'financial_institution',
    'mortgage_company',
    'medical_establishment',
    'insurance_agency'
))

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('SELECT * FROM company WHERE is_',CORPORATION, ' = ' ,FAMILY_ID  );
```